# npm install -g phonegap not working

Tags: node.js, cordova

i am trying to install phonegap in my win8 laptop from terminal. My NodeJs version is 1.4.14, my git version is 1.9.4.msysgit.0
The output looks like this:

```
C:\Users\sanjog>npm install -g phonegap
C:\Users\sanjog\AppData\Roaming\npm\phonegap -> C:\Users\sanjog\AppData\Roaming\
npm\node_modules\phonegap\bin\phonegap.js
phonegap@3.5.0-0.20.4 C:\Users\sanjog\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap
├── pluralize@0.0.4
├── colors@0.6.0-1
├── semver@1.1.0
├── qrcode-terminal@0.9.4
├── optimist@0.6.0 (wordwrap@0.0.2, minimist@0.0.10)
├── shelljs@0.1.4
├── prompt@0.2.11 (revalidator@0.1.8, pkginfo@0.3.0, read@1.0.5, utile@0.2.1, wi
nston@0.6.2)
├── phonegap-build@0.8.4 (qrcode-terminal@0.8.0, optimist@0.3.7, shelljs@0.0.9,
phonegap-build-api@0.3.3)
├── connect-phonegap@0.11.0 (home-dir@0.1.2, connect-inject@0.3.2, request-progr
ess@0.3.1, shelljs@0.2.6, node-static@0.7.0, tar@0.1.19, request@2.33.0, gaze@0.
4.3, useragent@2.0.8, connect@2.12.0)
├── cordova@3.5.0-0.2.4 (q@0.9.7, underscore@1.4.4, cordova-lib@0.21.3)
└── cordova-lib@0.21.4-dev (osenv@0.0.3, properties-parser@0.2.3, bplist-parser@
0.0.5, mime@1.2.11, q@0.9.7, semver@2.0.11, plist-with-patches@0.5.1, underscore
@1.4.4, dep-graph@1.1.0, npmconf@0.1.16, rc@0.3.0, glob@3.2.11, xcode@0.6.6, tar
@0.1.20, elementtree@0.1.5, request@2.22.0, npm@1.3.4)
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I was not sure whether the phonegap has installed or not and i got the solution already.

Comment: I also didn't realise this meant the installation was a success. You get one thumbs up from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it was installed just fine, no error to be seen.

Comment: i didn't knew this, anyway thanks :) i will move forward